# How to do two DB queries at once in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have two queries but can I have them as just one

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE title='$title' LIMIT 1");
$sql = ("UPDATE table SET views = views+1 where title='$title' ");
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error Connecting To db");
```

At the moment the 2nd one works but not the first one.

Comment: You are not running the first query.  You are overwriting `$sql`.  Try execution the query after you assign it to a string.

Comment: your first query didn't work because `$sql` got overwritten by the second one

Comment: well thanks guys for get my ability to ask questions on this account banned

Comment: @user3599634: don't take it personally. Downvotes are just a signal that someone thought your question was not a good fit for this site, or that it was not sufficiently researched, or some other problem. The increase in downvoting recently may also [be due to this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow) - i.e. people are minded to downvote more in order to improve question quality generally, in order to keep good answerers around. As I am sure you can appreciate, it's a hard balance to strike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your code:

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE title='$title' LIMIT 1");
$sql = ("UPDATE table SET views = views+1 where title='$title' ");
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error Connecting To db");
```

First, the first `$sql` will not run because you are overwriting the contents of that first `$sql` with new content in the next line.

Then just looking at your logic, here is your first query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE title='$title' LIMIT 1
```

I assume that is to get the entry with the `title` equalling `$title` and nothing else, right? But then your next query is this:

```
UPDATE table SET views = views+1 where title='$title'
```

You are updating the value where `title='$title'` anyway.  So the first query is not even needed.  So problem solved, right? Well you might want to add the `LIMIT 1` to the second query like this:

```
UPDATE table SET views = views+1 where title='$title' LIMIT 1
```

But honestly the logic of updating a DB based on whether an item `title` matches seems messy. What if two items have the same title? Yes, you are limiting things by `1` but by what criteria? If you have three items with the same title, which gets updated?

You need more differentiation for your app structure. But I think that is fair for what is essentially a newbie question.

Comment: Thanks you that was very helpful. I tried just using the update line as you suggested but it didn't work possible because i have a while loop underneath just assigning variables to rows in the database? but im not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Run the two queries separately

```
$sql1 = ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE title='$title' LIMIT 1");
$qry  = mysql_query($sql1);
if (mysql_num_rows($qry) > 0)
{
  while ($res = mysql_fetch_object($qry))
  {
  // -- contents --
  }


  $sql = ("UPDATE table SET views = views+1 where title='$title' ");
  $query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error Connecting To db");
}
```